# Bokeh Interactive legend hide multiple glyphs

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

I've enabled the hide legend option for my dataset. When I click it, only one bar goes off and others stay. I'm not quite sure what is causing the issue.

Here's the bar plot before and after:

[image: before and after].

Here's what my data looks like:

[image: Here's]

Here's the code:

```
p = Bar(output,'Programs',values="Averages", group="University",plot_width=600,plot_height=400, title="Comparison")
p.legend.click_policy="hide"
output_file("bar.html")
show(p)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not currently (Bokeh 0.12.6) possible to hide all the bars via `legend.click_policy="hide"`, as stated in the [documentation](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/legends.html):

> Interactive legend features currently work on “per-glyph” legends. Legends that are created by specifying a column to automatically group do no yet work with the features described below

It is, however, possible to hide the bars by adding [CheckboxGroup()](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/widgets.groups.html#bokeh.models.widgets.groups.CheckboxGroup) with CustomJS that hides the bars when the checkboxes are clicked. Below you can see an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which is also [available online as a Jupyter Notebook](https://kyso.io/tuomastik/bokeh_interactive_legend_hide_multiple_glyphs):

```
import numpy as np
from bkcharts import Bar, show
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import CheckboxGroup, CustomJS

data = {'University': ['ENGT'] * 3 + ['UBC'] * 3,
        'Averages': [76.5, 79.9, 72.2, 71, 72, 69],
        'Programs': ['CHML', 'CIVL', 'CPEN', 'CHML', 'CIVL', 'CPEN']}

group = "University"
bars = Bar(data=data, label='Programs', values="Averages", group=group,
           plot_width=600, plot_height=400, title="Comparison")

checkboxes = CheckboxGroup(labels=np.unique(data[group]).tolist(),
                           # Make all checkboxes checked by default
                           active=list(range(np.unique(data[group]).size)))
checkboxes.callback = CustomJS(args=dict(bars=bars), code="""

var group = '%s';

function change_bars_visibility(checkbox_name, visible) {
    for (j = 0; j < bars.renderers.length; j++) {
        // Go through rendered objects

        if (bars.renderers[j].attributes.hasOwnProperty('data_source') && 
            bars.renderers[j].data_source.data[group][0] === checkbox_name) {

            // Change the visibility of this rendered object if it belongs to
            // the group determined by the checkbox that was clicked
            bars.renderers[j].visible = visible;
        }
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < cb_obj.labels.length; i++) {
    // Go through checkbox labels
    var checkbox_name = cb_obj.labels[i];

    if (cb_obj.active.indexOf(i) >= 0) {
        // alert(checkbox_name + " is activated");
        change_bars_visibility(checkbox_name, true);
    }
    else {
        // alert(checkbox_name + " is disabled");
        change_bars_visibility(checkbox_name, false);
    }
}
""" % group)

show(column(bars, checkboxes))
```

Comment: Has there been any updates to this now that Bokeh is in version 1.2.0?

Comment: I'm afraid that today in [Bokeh 1.3.0](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/legends.html) it is still the same. I tried implementing an interactive legend in an hbar plot. I wanted to mute some bars. When clicking in an element in the legend, the whole legend goes semitransparent, but the bars remain unchanged.