# How to replace the legend in interactive Bokeh graph, rather than augment the legend?

Tags: python, bokeh

I am using a selection dropdown in Bokeh to change what the chart shows. I'd also like the chart's legend to change accordingly. However, what happens instead is the legend becomes augmented every time the user selects a new dropdown value. Eventually, the legend displays every value from every possible dropdown option simultaneously. How do I "clear" the old legend on every new dropdown select?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os

from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import output_file, show, save, curdoc
from bokeh.models import HoverTool, CategoricalColorMapper, BoxSelectTool
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Select, Range1d
from bokeh.layouts import row, column, gridplot
from bokeh.models.widgets import Panel, Tabs
from bokeh.transform import factor_cmap

team = ['Bears', 'Bears', 'Bears', 'Bears', 'Bears']
player = ['Charles Leno', 'James Daniels', 'Cody Whitehair', 'Kyle Long', 'Bobby Massie']
position = ['LT', 'LG', 'C', 'RG', 'RT']
year_acquired = [2014, 2018, 2016, 2013, 2016]
round_drafted = [7, 2, 2, 1, np.NaN]
star=[False, False, False, True, False]

position_loc_x = [-4, -2, 0, 2, 4]
position_loc_y = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

year_acquired_color = ['green', 'yellow', 'blue', 'purple', 'blue']
round_drafted_color = ['grey', 'green', 'green', 'purple', np.NaN]
star_color = ['black', 'black', 'black', 'red', 'black']

df = pd.DataFrame({'team':team, 'player':player, 'position':position, 'year_acquired':year_acquired, 
                   'round_drafted':round_drafted, 'star':star, 'position_loc_x':position_loc_x, 
                   'position_loc_y':position_loc_y, 'year_acquired_color':year_acquired_color, 
                   'round_drafted_color':round_drafted_color, 'star_color':star_color})

p = figure(x_range=[-5,5], y_range=[-5, 5])

source = ColumnDataSource(data=df)

p.rect(source=source, x='position_loc_x', y=0, width=1, height=1, line_width=5, line_color=None,
       fill_color='round_drafted_color', legend='round_drafted')

hover = HoverTool(tooltips=[('Name', '@player'), ('Round', '@round_drafted'), ('Year', '@year_acquired')])
p.add_tools(hover)

def update():
    p.rect(source=source, x='position_loc_x', y=0, width=1, height=1, line_width=5, line_color=None, 
           fill_color=select.value, legend=select.value.rpartition('_')[0])

select = Select(title='choose an attribute', options=['round_drafted_color', 'year_acquired_color', 'star_color'], 
               value = 'round_drafted_color')

select.on_change('value', lambda attr, old, new: update())

p.legend.click_policy="hide"

layout = column(select, p)
curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of plotting the rectangle again with a new color/legendname, you should update the ColumnDataSource used to plot the rectangles. You can do this by editing the `source.data` dictionary.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os

from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import output_file, show, save, curdoc
from bokeh.models import HoverTool, CategoricalColorMapper, BoxSelectTool
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Select, Range1d
from bokeh.layouts import row, column, gridplot
from bokeh.models.widgets import Panel, Tabs
from bokeh.transform import factor_cmap

team = ['Bears', 'Bears', 'Bears', 'Bears', 'Bears']
player = ['Charles Leno', 'James Daniels', 'Cody Whitehair', 'Kyle Long', 'Bobby Massie']
position = ['LT', 'LG', 'C', 'RG', 'RT']
year_acquired = [2014, 2018, 2016, 2013, 2016]
round_drafted = [7, 2, 2, 1, np.NaN]
star=[False, False, False, True, False]

position_loc_x = [-4, -2, 0, 2, 4]
position_loc_y = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

year_acquired_color = ['green', 'yellow', 'blue', 'purple', 'blue']
round_drafted_color = ['grey', 'green', 'green', 'purple', np.NaN]
star_color = ['black', 'black', 'black', 'red', 'black']

df = pd.DataFrame({'team':team, 'player':player, 'position':position, 'year_acquired':year_acquired, 
                   'round_drafted':round_drafted, 'star':star, 'position_loc_x':position_loc_x, 
                   'position_loc_y':position_loc_y, 'year_acquired_color':year_acquired_color, 
                   'round_drafted_color':round_drafted_color, 'star_color':star_color, 'legend':round_drafted, 'color':round_drafted_color})

p = figure(x_range=[-5,5], y_range=[-5, 5])

source = ColumnDataSource(data=df)

glyph = p.rect(source=source, x='position_loc_x', y=0, width=1, height=1, line_width=5, line_color=None,
       fill_color='color', legend='legend')

hover = HoverTool(tooltips=[('Name', '@player'), ('Round', '@round_drafted'), ('Year', '@year_acquired')])
p.add_tools(hover)

def update():
    #Use select.value to get the right key from the dictionary and set its list as color/legend item
    source.data['color'] = source.data[select.value]
    source.data['legend'] = source.data[select.value.replace('_color', '')]


select = Select(title='choose an attribute', options=['round_drafted_color', 'year_acquired_color', 'star_color'], 
               value = 'round_drafted_color')

select.on_change('value', lambda attr, old, new: update())

p.legend.click_policy="hide"

layout = column(select, p)
curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

Comment: Thank you, that works! But there is another remaining problem that I thought would be fixed: clicking on a legend element to hide it instead hides the entire legend. Any suggestions?


I think my brain just doesn't get the basics of how Bokeh works in general, and there doesn't appear to be much good documentation out there. The official docs provide only the most simplistic examples, and once I need to use a combo of 2+ Bokeh features at once, I'm lost.

Comment: https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/legends.html ~ "Interactive legend features currently work on “per-glyph” legends. Legends that are created by specifying a column to automatically group do no yet work with the features described below". It is possible to work around this problem by using some CustomJS and checkboxes as explained in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45380781/bokeh-interactive-legend-hide-multiple-glyphs