# Dynamically adding and removing Bokeh legends

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm trying to develop a relatively complex plotting application, which has a huge selection of data to plot. Using dropdowns, the user can select which lines they would like to plot. I've developed a largely simplified version of the code (shown below) to illustrate what my application is like.

```
import bokeh.plotting.figure as bk_figure
import random
import numpy as np
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.layouts import row, column, widgetbox
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Legend, LegendItem, Line
from bokeh.models.widgets import MultiSelect
from bokeh.io import output_notebook # enables plot interface in J notebook
from bokeh.application import Application
from bokeh.application.handlers import FunctionHandler

global x, ys

output_notebook()

plot = bk_figure(plot_width=950, plot_height=800, title="Legend Test Plot"\
        , x_axis_label="X Value", y_axis_label="Y Value")
lines = ['0','1','2']
line_select = MultiSelect(title='Line Select', value = [lines[0]],options=lines)

x = np.linspace(0,10,10)
ys = []
#generates three different lines
for i in range(len(lines)):
    ys.append(x*i)

#add line 0 to plot initially
source = ColumnDataSource(data={'x':x,'y':ys[0]})
glyph = Line(x='x',y='y')
glyph = plot.add_glyph(source,glyph)

def change_line(attr,old,new):

    #remove old lines
    render_copy = list(plot.renderers)
    for line in render_copy:
        plot.renderers.remove(line)

    legend_items = []

    #add selected lines to plot
    for i,line in enumerate(line_select.value):
        y = ys[int(line)]
        source = ColumnDataSource(data={'x':x,'y':y})
        glyph = Line(x='x',y='y')
        glyph = plot.add_glyph(source,glyph)

line_select.on_change('value',change_line)

layout = column(line_select,plot)

def modify_doc(doc):
    doc.add_root(row(layout,width=800))
    doc.title = "PlumeDataVis"

handler = FunctionHandler(modify_doc)
app = Application(handler)
show(app)
```

I've decided to dynamically add and remove line glyphs from the plot as they are selected in the MultiSelect. This is because if I simply hide the lines, the performance of the program suffers, given that there are so many line options in the real dataset.

**Problem:**
I want to add a legend to the plot which only contains entries for the Line glyphs that are currently in the plot (there are far too many line options in the real dataset to have all of them visible in the legend at all times.) I've been having issues finding any resources to help with this: for most applications, something like [this](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/annotations.html#legends) is sufficient, but this doesn't work with the way I've defined the lines I'm plotting.

I've been adding legends [manually](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/annotations.html#manual-legends), for example:

```
#add line 0 to plot initially
source = ColumnDataSource(data={'x':x,'y':ys[0]})
glyph = Line(x='x',y='y')
glyph = plot.add_glyph(source,glyph)

#create first legend
legend_item = [LegendItem(label=lines[0],\
                        renderers=[glyph])]
legend = Legend(items=legend_item)
plot.add_layout(legend,place='right')
```

but I can't figure out how to effectively remove the legend layouts from the plot once I've added them. After reading the [source code](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/_modules/bokeh/models/plots.html#Plot.add_layout) for add_layout, I realized that you could get a list of layouts in a  given location by using something like getattr(plot,'right'). Trying to use this, I replaced the change_line function with the following:

```
def change_line(attr,old,new):

    #remove old lines
    render_copy = list(plot.renderers)
    for line in render_copy:
        plot.renderers.remove(line)

    #remove old legend
    right_attrs_copy = list(getattr(plot,'right'))
    for legend in right_attrs_copy:
        getattr(plot,'right').remove(legend)

    legend_items = []

    #add selected lines to plot
    for i,line in enumerate(line_select.value):
        y = ys[int(line)]
        source = ColumnDataSource(data={'x':x,'y':y})
        glyph = Line(x='x',y='y')
        glyph = plot.add_glyph(source,glyph)

        legend_items.append(LegendItem(label='line '+str(line),\
                        renderers=[glyph]))


    #create legend
    legend = Legend(items=legend_items)
    plot.add_layout(legend,place='right')
```

Checking the attributes of the plot, this appears to add and remove legends and lines correctly, but it causes the plot to completely stop visually updating.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this behavior? It's possible that I'm not even adding the legend in the correct way, but I couldn't figure out how else to add them when lines are defined as Glyph objects.

Comment: In general, removing items doesn't work as well because sometimes Bokeh caches some values. You should still be able to make it performant - e.g. you can try changing the glyph renderer's `data_source` and the corresponding legend item's `label`.

Comment: Do you know the syntax one can use to access and change those values? Using something like getattr(plot,'right')[0].items yields a object of class 'bokeh.core.property.wrappers.PropertyValueList', rather than the LegendItem that I'm trying to access.

Comment: Don't use `getattr` if you know the property name, just write `plot.right` - it's the same exact thing. `.items` returns a kind of list that Bokeh uses internally. Just get its `[0]` element to get to the first legend item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much anguish, I finally figured it out ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54273406/how-to-replace-the-legend-in-interactive-bokeh-graph-rather-than-augment-the-le) link was helpful). @Eugene Pakhomov was correct in that the fact that I removed lines and legends in my initial code was a problem. Instead, the key was to initialize a new line only when the user requested to plot a new maximum number of lines. In all other cases, you can simply edit the data_source of existing lines. This allows the program to avoid having all the lines plotted and hidden when the user only wants to plot one or two of the total options.

Instead of deleting and remaking the legend, you can set it to be empty on every update, then add entries as needed.

The following code worked for me in a Jupyter Notebook running bokeh 1.4.0:

```
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Legend, LegendItem, Line
from bokeh.models.widgets import MultiSelect
from bokeh.io import output_notebook
from bokeh.application import Application
from bokeh.application.handlers import FunctionHandler
from bokeh.palettes import Category10 as palette

output_notebook()

plot = bk_figure(plot_width=750, plot_height=600, title="Legend Test Plot"\
        , x_axis_label="X Value", y_axis_label="Y Value")
lines = ['0','1','2']
line_select = MultiSelect(title='Line Select', value = [lines[0]],options=lines)

x = np.linspace(0,10,10)

ys = []
#generates three different lines with 0,1, and 2 slope
for i in range(len(lines)):
    ys.append(x*i)

#add line 0 to plot initially
source = ColumnDataSource(data={'x':x,'y':ys[0]})
glyph = Line(x='x',y='y')
glyph = plot.add_glyph(source,glyph)

#intialize Legend
legend = Legend(items=[LegendItem(label=lines[0],renderers=[glyph])])
plot.add_layout(legend)

def change_line(attr,old,new):
    plot.legend.items = [] #reset the legend

    #add selected lines to plot
    for i,line in enumerate(line_select.value):
        line_num = int(line)
        color = palette[10][i]

        #if i lines have already been plotted in the past, just edit an existing line
        if i < len(plot.renderers):
            #edit the existing line's data source
            plot.renderers[i]._property_values['data_source'].data = {'x':x, 'y':ys[line_num]}

            #Add a new legend entry
            plot.legend.items.append(LegendItem(label=line,renderers=[plot.renderers[i]]))

        #otherwise, initialize an entirely new line
        else:
            #create a new glyph with a new data source
            source = ColumnDataSource(data={'x':x,'y':ys[line_num]})
            glyph = Line(x='x',y='y',line_color=color)
            glyph = plot.add_glyph(source,glyph)

            #Add a new legend entry
            plot.legend.items.append(LegendItem(label=line,renderers=[plot.renderers[i]]))

    #'Remove' all extra lines by making them contain no data
    #instead of outright deleting them, which Bokeh dislikes
    for extra_line_num in range(i+1,len(plot.renderers)):
        plot.renderers[extra_line_num]._property_values['data_source'].data = {'x':[],'y':[]}


line_select.on_change('value',change_line)

layout = column(line_select,plot)

def modify_doc(doc):
    doc.add_root(row(layout,width=800))
    doc.title = "PlumeDataVis"

handler = FunctionHandler(modify_doc)
app = Application(handler)
show(app)
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic glyphs provide much flexibility compared to chart/model classes. A basic `line` (not `Line`) glyph can be used here.

In the code below, I am adding basic glyphs to the chart. I am saving the glyphs in a dictionary which can be actioned later (as OP said its a complex application, I am sure this will be used later). I have commented the ColumnDataSource creation, as it will accessible through `data_source.data` of respective glyphs (now saved in dictionary).

Also, since now we are creating lines one by one, color needs to be provided for different lines. I have used a `bokeh.palette` function to generate a number of colors. More on this can be read [here](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/palettes.html)

```
import bokeh.plotting.figure as bk_figure
import random
import numpy as np
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.layouts import row, column, widgetbox
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Legend, LegendItem, Line
from bokeh.models.widgets import MultiSelect
from bokeh.io import output_notebook # enables plot interface in J notebook
from bokeh.application import Application
from bokeh.application.handlers import FunctionHandler
import bokeh.palettes

#change the number as per the max number of glyphs in system
palette = bokeh.palettes.inferno(5)

global x, ys

output_notebook()

plot = bk_figure(plot_width=950, plot_height=800, title="Legend Test Plot"\
        , x_axis_label="X Value", y_axis_label="Y Value")
lines = ['0','1','2']
line_select = MultiSelect(title='Line Select', value = [lines[0]],options=lines)

x = np.linspace(0,10,10)
ys = []
#generates three different lines
for i in range(len(lines)):
    ys.append(x*i)

linedict = {}    

#add line 0 to plot initially
#source = ColumnDataSource(data={'x':x,'y':ys[0]})
#glyph = Line(x='x',y='y')
#glyph = plot.add_glyph(source,glyph)
l1 = plot.line(x = x, y= ys[0], legend=str(0), color = palette[0])
linedict[str(0)] = l1


def change_line(attr,old,new):

    #remove old lines
    render_copy = list(plot.renderers)
    for line in render_copy:
        plot.renderers.remove(line)

    legend_items = []

    #add selected lines to plot
    for i,line in enumerate(line_select.value):
        y = ys[int(line)]
        #source = ColumnDataSource(data={'x':x,'y':y})
        l1 = plot.line(x = x, y= y, legend=line, color = palette[i])
        #linedict[line] = l1
        glyph = Line(x='x',y='y', legend=line, color = palette[i])
        glyph = plot.add_glyph(source,glyph)

line_select.on_change('value',change_line)

layout = column(line_select,plot)

def modify_doc(doc):
    doc.add_root(row(layout,width=800))
    doc.title = "PlumeDataVis"

handler = FunctionHandler(modify_doc)
app = Application(handler)
show(app)
```

Comment: This code doesn't seem to solve the issue with the plot that keeps zooming in. Also, you have the wrong lines commented out in the function: I believe you wanted to comment out the lines starting with glyph, not the ones which add the lines using plot.line

Comment: @jgholder Thanks for pointing out comment part, can you please let me know what is the issue with zooming-in ?

Comment: Your code seems to place an entire new plot on top of the old one each time a selection is made, making the plot appear to be zoomed in and cut off. [This album](https://ibb.co/album/kXEttv) shows the behavior: 'noselect' is the initial plot. 'oneselect' is the plot after a selection has been made, and 'multiselect' is the plot after many selections have been made.